# How to calculate cumulative density from a dynamical output?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, summation, time-series, result-accumulation

I am running a simulation. I want to calculate the cumulate density of each species "C" and "R" from 0 to 100 [I just need the final number, not a graph]. Here is a sample equation

```
dRnum = r'[t] == u*r[t] - f*r[t]*c[t]
dCnum = c'[t] == e*f*r[t]*c[t] - d*c[t]

Pars = {u -> 1, f -> 0.5, e -> 0.7, d -> 0.2};

LVsolve1 = 
  NDSolve[{dRnum /. Pars, dCnum /. Pars, r[0] == 0.75, 
    c[0] == 1.75}, {r[t], c[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];

PlotLVTime1 = 
 Plot[Evaluate[{r[t], c[t]} /. LVsolve1], {t, 0, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 4}}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "R and C"}]
```

Comment: do you just want `LVSolve1/.t->100`?

Comment: @ubpdqn Nope. I want the cumulative i.e. sum from t = 0 to t = 100.

Comment: ‘NIntegrate[r[t]/.LVsolve1, {t,0,100}]’

Comment: @ubpdqn Can you please post this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per request:

```
NIntegrate[#, {t, 0, 100}] & /@ ({r[t], c[t]} /. LVsolve1[[1]])
```

This  yields: {57.3204, 199.836}

I do not the context, units/dimensionless or ultimate aim or whether this accords with expectations.